# Evaluate xpath selector to get text in p- and li-tags

Tags: xpath

For purposes to automatically replace keywords with links based on a list of keyword-link pairs I need to get text that is not already linked, not a script or manually excluded, inside paragraphs (p) and list items (li) –- to be used in Drupal's [Alinks](https://www.drupal.org/project/alinks) module.

I modified the existing xpath selector as follows and would like to get feedback on it, if it is efficient or might be improved:

```
//*[p or li]//text()[not(ancestor::a) and not(ancestor::script) and not(ancestor::*[@data-alink-ignore])]
```

The xpath is meant to work with any html5 content, also with self closing tags (not well-formed xml) -- that's the way the module was designed, and it works quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to select text node descendant of `p` or `li` elements that are not descendant of `a` or `script` elements, you can use this XPath 1.0:

```
//*[self::p|self::li]
   //text()[
      not(ancestor::a|ancestor::script|ancestor::*[@data-alink-ignore])
   ]
```

Comment: What is the difference between `//*[self::p|self::li]` and `//*[p|li]`?

Comment: @LarS The difference is that `//*[p|li]` will select an element with `p` or `li` childs and `//*[self::p|self::li]` will select those `p` or `li` elements. That may have no impact in your code because you then go down the hierarchy with `//tex()`. But, in case `p` or `li` had no parent (ei. root elements) the expression `//*[p|li]` will not work.

Comment: Thank you, @Alejandro for explaining the details.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression is invalid. You are missing a `/` before `text()`. So a valid expression would be

```
//*[p or li]/text()[not(ancestor::a) and not(ancestor::script) and not(ancestor::*[@data-alink-ignore])]
```

But without an XML source file it is impossible to tell if this expression would match your desired node.

Comment: Thank you @zx485 for reviewing the expression. I corrected it in the question. I was experimenting with it, and copied the version that was not working. With the `/` before `text()` it does not work, but with `//`. It should work with any html5 content, also with self closing tags (not well-formed).